# Cross Browser Radio Input Checking

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a large group of radio buttons and I would like to check one of them with a javascript function that takes in the radio set name and the value.  On Chrome, radio buttons don't seem to be  grouped into a array like the select tag options. Do I have to do something like put them all in a div and iterate through it's controls or is there an easier way that I am not seeing?

thanks

Comment: please include some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jQuery for this:

`$('input:radio[name=myRadioGroup]:checked').val();`

You can also use `document.getElementsByName("myRadioGroup")` and then iterate through to get the checked value...

```
getSelectedRadioButton = function (buttons) {
    var option = -1;
    for (i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        if (buttons[i].checked) {
            option = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (option === -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return buttons[i];
    }
};
```

Ot to set a radio button with a given value attribute to checked:

```
setRadioWithValToChecked = function (buttons, val) {
    for (i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].checked = false;
        if (buttons[i].value === val.toString()) {
            buttons[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want to get the checked radio I want to set one of them.  But this helps.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using jQuery or a similar library?